# Display image on a web page that is not copy-able

Tags: html, image

Is there a way to display an image on a webpage such that it won't be copied if the surrounding text is copied?

For instance, I'd like to be able to put a diagonal up arrow after hyperlinks opening in a new window, but I'd like users to be able to copy the link with its surrounding content without copying the up arrow image.

Possible without extravagant CSS?

EDIT: I don't care if the user has access to the image, I just want a streamlined copy-paste experience.

Comment: Like they do on wikipedia?  I just tested there (FF10) and I could select and copy the text without copying the image as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a background image in the CSS of an element like a `<div>`, but if they want a copy of the image there are still ways of getting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a CSS background-image on a div for example, it will not get copied.

Answer (score 0):

Use div and background image for that div, if you can.